# Migrating a question from Serverfault to Unix & Linux

Tags: discussion

I'd like https://serverfault.com/questions/359255/effects-of-ddos-attacks-on-memory-use-under-linux/ migrated to this site.

Comment: Then flag it on the other site as off topic and indicate that it would be better served by this site

Comment: It's been closed by the moderators there as off-topic. They didn't explain why they consider it off-topic - due to its' research nature, due to being a Linux question, or what? Their FAQ doesn't state that questions can't be about Linux - I didn't notice this site before.

Comment: This doesn't belong to either this site or serverfault.com.  This probably belongs to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8431/it-security

Comment: I thought Area 51 was about aliens... has it not occured to anyone to give it a more intuitive name?

Comment: @nlovric — note that the question there wasn't closed by moderators but rather by community consensus.

Comment: @Karlson IT Security has a real URL now: http://security.stackexchange.com. No need to link to the original site proposal. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Good to know.  I just remembered seeing it Are51.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've now [reposted the question on IT Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11632/effects-of-ddos-attacks-on-memory-use-under-linux), this instance is moot, but for future reference:

- The proper procedure to request migrating a question is to flag it on the site where it's posted (use the `flag` button under the question).
- I think the topic of this question could work on either [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), emphasizing different aspects on each site.
- Opening with “Can someone … give me exact data [from their system]” is likely to provoke negative reactions on Stack Exchange, where we tend to eschew personal involvement (at least on the more technical computer-related sites, especially Server Fault). Your later impersonal request “I'd like to know how various DDoS tools effect memory …” is better (btw, it's *affect*) is likely to get a better reception.

Comment: Well, I wrote "I'd like to know", because "I want to know" is, basically, demanding. Also, it's not absolutely neccessary that I know this; if I don't know this, I just can't adjust the program against DDoS tools.